# Winter Bash Login Bug

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2016

To reproduce

1. Go to https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com
2. It informs you are not logged in (bottom right corner)
3. Log in
4. The not logged in message doesn't go away.

[image]

Running Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: status-norepro here

Comment: Worked fine for me too, no-repo here same Firefox version, but on macOS.

Comment: Caused by SOX and has been fixed. See my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288282/267099)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's caused by [SOX](https://github.com/soscripted/sox).

Disabling this user extension removes the box and link from the bottom right corner.

It has been [reported](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/160) to the SOX maintainers.

Confirmed as fixed by [ᔕᖺᘎᕊ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260841/%e1%94%95%e1%96%ba%e1%98%8e%e1%95%8a) in [SOX 2.0.2 DEV al](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js)

Answer (score 12):

That thing is not part of the Winter Bash page. Wherever your browser gets that from, it's not us. Browser extension? Malware?

Comment: It was caused by SOX. I've reported it there.

Comment: @David sorry, it is a SOX bug. I'm working on it now!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ You have an open ticket for it https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/160 :)